# Kivy: Bad Audio Management

Tags: android, python, audio, kivy, frame-rate

Has anyone come up with a solution for playing audio in Kivy (on android or ios) and not having the fps drop because the main loop freezes when playing a sound?

I thought the issue was within SoundLoader but after bypassing SoundLoader and using the sound modules directly, I discovered that Pygame will play without fps drop on PC but on android, the same issue occurs.

The pygstplayer module has the same problem on any platform.  The fact Pygame sound dropped the fps tells me the issue runs much deeper in Kivy.

You can't use threading because "A", it won't working on android and "B", the main loop will still freeze during soundplay, which causes the fps drop (and choppy play).

I'm guessing no one has come up with a solution to none fps drop sound play on hand-helds with Kivy.  What really bugs me is the fact this problem was somehow missed...?  How could Kivy Devs miss something like that so it must have been over looked.

---

PS,

Hate the fact kivy has gone all linux.  Why not Windows installers for kivy?

Comment: So seems like you're not very familiar with Python or kivy. The only way I can say this nicely is just learn how to optimize your code. I've never had any issues like that. Optimization of your project is not something the kivy devs can do for you. Lol says he doesn't like that kivy "has gone all linux". What does that even mean... don't answer please I don't need or want to know.

Comment: Actually, been using python since the early dawn of the language.  If you're not familiar with kivy's audio issue, then you haven't developed anything worth wild using kivy because the issues is already known, goggle it.  When is the last time you seen a kivy Windows installer?  The statement kivy has gone all Linux is self explanatory.  Seriously, if you don't know the answer to an issue, don't answer because insulting ends up being foolish if you're insulting someone who has years of programming experience.  Kivy is not a super great api set; it has way more cons than pros.

Comment: Optimization is always at the top of my list and has nothing to do with kivy's hick-up during sound play.  This issue is actually a lot softer on the android OS but is still noticeable if multiple sounds play at once.  At present, I have smoothed things out.  Kivy is a poor api set but the best thing for python users who want to enter the world of hand-helds.

Comment: PS,  kivy version 1.9.0....  Maybe you're using the newest and the issue was fixed (I doubt it).

Comment: "threading ...  it won't working on android" false. "the main loop will still freeze during soundplay" nope even without [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) iirc, `pygstplayer` has been deprecated *and* **removed**, `pygame` has been replaced with `sdl2` and re the windows installers - [there are wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kivy) which basically means that you can `pip install kivy` without any installer. And then there's this [unofficial](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) installer I made. Also, the latest stable version is `1.10.0`.